# Keeping the code readable in my liquid tags list snippet

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I have some code to filter out the display of certain tags on my shopify product page template.
It reads in this comma separated list of tags I want to exclude from display on the product page:

```
{% assign exclude_tags = "Dangerous Goods,Quick Links,ShippingLetter,ShippingParcel" | split: ',' %}
```

And the product page reads in that snippet:

```
{% include "excluded-tags" %}
```

...and excludes tags from being displayed if they are found in the exclude_tags list:

```
{%- for tag in product.tags -%}
{% if exclude_tags contains tag %}
{% continue %}
{% endif %}
```

And that all works perfectly fine.
However, this list of tags to exclude is going to end up quite large (lets say there might be 100 tags here!!), and I want to keep it readable for later editing etc, so I tried changing the comma separated list to one item per line in the code editor, but it stops working when I do that? Items that should be hidden on the product page are not hidden doing it that way.

Is there a way to achieve this instead of having the comma separated values all on a single line of code, something that looks like this:

```
{% assign exclude_tags = "Dangerous Goods,
Quick Links,
ShippingLetter,
ShippingParcel" | split: ',' %}
```

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [capture](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/tags/variable-tags#capture) to assign multiline text to a Liquid variable and then use split to convert it to Array.

```
{% capture exclude_tags %}
  Dangerous Goods,
  Quick Links,
  ShippingLetter,
  ShippingParcel
{% endcapture %}
    
{% assign exclude_tags = exclude_tags | split: ',' %}
```

However, as per you above code snippet, you don't need to use split. You can use contains with a string. So your code will become just this

```
{% capture exclude_tags %}
  Dangerous Goods,
  Quick Links,
  ShippingLetter,
  ShippingParcel
{% endcapture %}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping it as hardcode in code file, you can save it under one container under theme customizer and then can see all together there. You have to edited liquid files to implement this.

for e.g.

[image: Please check this screenshot]